# Lubuntu 18.04.3 Wi-Fi not working, tried different things

Tags: wireless, lubuntu, hot-spot, rtl8723be

I have started using Lubuntu recently on my laptop to lengthen its lifespan (the machine is kinda old and Windows was crashing on a regular basis) but now I'm having a very hard time with wi-fi.
Wired connections work just fine, but recently my modem had problems and I tried to use my phone as hotspot but the pc won't collaborate.

My laptop is an HP and it has a Realtek RTL8723BE.
In the beginning it recognized WiFi connections, it connected (allegedly), but it didn't actually work.
I went to my friend's house and used his Ethernet connection, looked online for solutions (like I did for setting up Bluetooth and other things), and tried them (some of them were directing to dead GitHub branches, but whatever).

What I have obtained is that my pc now doesn't even list WiFi connections anymore (lol). Wired connections still work tho.

I'm writing from my phone now. Can someone please guide me step by step to solve this problem? I know how to open the terminal, insert commands, intall things etc. but I'm afraid that this time things are a little more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Find the download for this : **rtlwifi_new-rock.new_btcoex**

Then do the usual stuff about "sel 1 or sel 2 modprobe" fixes (most advise this) - important to rem to reboot between each trial - one or other will work. Then the common advice to make it permanent on boot.

Then pin your kernel - so it stays as it is - pain to have to keep doing all this!!

```
sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-4.4.0-157-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-157-generic
```